# I want to add an image inside of heredoc in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

When i do this it does not show the image and i don't know why it is not working. I have tried this with other code and it is working for my title but when i try to do it for my images it is not working.

```
 <?php
      foreach ($result as $row) {
          echo <<<_END
           <img src="<?php echo base_url('application/' . $row->image)?>" alt=""/>
_END;

      }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a bit overkill, but if you absolutely wanted to use a heredoc statement you would need to reference the function from a variable:

```
$base_url = 'base_url';

foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo <<<_END
    <img src="{$base_url('application/' . $row->image)}" alt=""/>
_END;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use simple things like :

```
 <?php
 foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo '<img src="'. base_url('application/' . $row->image) .'" alt=""/>';
 } ?>
```

Comment: is there a way to put a echo in a variable

Comment: Yes, replace `echo` by `$variable .=`